# pagination in php limiting data but not displaying in the next page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have a php website which list data from database, there is a search button in my hompage, when the user searches a keyword, the user is taken to this page displaying data. i have done the following code to list data and do the pagination

```html
<?php
  session_start();
?>


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Search Result</title>






  </head>

  <body style="height:100%; width:100%">

    <header>
      <div class="header">
        <h2>LOGO</h2>

      </div>

      <div id="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="main.php">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
      </div>

    </header>



    <?php

$limit = 8;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sample");
 
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
if(isset($_REQUEST["search"])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery WHERE keyq LIKE ? OR keyw LIKE ? OR keye LIKE ? OR keyr LIKE ? OR keyt LIKE ? OR keyy LIKE ? OR keyu LIKE ? OR keyi LIKE ? OR keyo LIKE ? OR keyp LIKE ? LIMIT $start_from, $limit ";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssssssss", $param_term, $king, $me, $you, $gig, $mig, $mug, $sug, $kez, $peb);

        
        $param_term = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $king = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $me = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $you = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $gig = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $mig = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $mug = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $sug = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $kez = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';
        $peb = $_REQUEST["search"] . '%';

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){?>




      <div class="aamir"><span><img style="height:40px; width:55px; " class="img-responsive" alt="" src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" /></span><small><?php echo $row['title']; ?></small><strong style="width:40%; height: 35%;"><em  class="icon icon-chevron-down"></em><p style="margin-top: -5%;"> <?php echo $row['description']; ?> </p></strong>
        <a
          class="zayan" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>">VISIT</a>
      </div>


      <?php }?>

      <?php

$results = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM image_gallery");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($results);
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
$pagLink = "<div class='pagination'>";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
             $pagLink .= "<a class='circle' href='view.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
};
echo $pagLink . "</div>";
?>

        <?php
                
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found <br> <a href='index.php'>Go Back</a></p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>





  </body>



  </html>
```

(NB: i have given the same keyword, so when i search that keyword , every data will display )the data is being limited fine, but the remaining data is not being shown in the next page of the pagination. can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

try to switch limit and start_from in your query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery WHERE keyq LIKE ? OR keyw LIKE ? OR keye LIKE ? OR keyr LIKE ? OR keyt LIKE ? OR keyy LIKE ? OR keyu LIKE ? OR keyi LIKE ? OR keyo LIKE ? OR keyp LIKE ? LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start_from";
```